# MySQL doesn't work properly when query is very big

Tags: mysql

When number of pIDs in query is very big - I don't receive expected results. More exactly - I receive nothing.

Note that the same query works OK on another server.

I think (but I'm not sure) that problem may be in MySQL configuration but don't know how to solve it.

Does anyone know how can I resolve this issue?

Query looks like this:

```
SELECT `filtID`,`pID` FROM (
  (SELECT `filtID`,`pID` FROM `ftox_params_prod_links` 
  LEFT JOIN `ftox_params_values` USING(`fvID`) 
  WHERE (`filtID` IN (1,4,5,14,15,302,303,304,388,389,390)))  
  UNION (SELECT `filtID`,`pID` FROM `ftox_params_prod_values` 
  WHERE (`filtID` IN (1,4,5,14,15,302,303,304,388,389,390)))) AS `_T_` 
  WHERE (`pID` IN   (173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,
                     184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,
                     198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209, ...
                     ....................................................
                     ...................Very much pIDs..................
                     ....................................................
   )) ORDER BY `filtID` ASC
```

Comment: May be the issue of `max_allowed_packet` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

Comment: max_allowed_packet = 64M - this is the value in config. My query size is 700 KB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a limit for a query size, defined by `max_allowed_packet` configuration value - in `my.conf`.

Or the result of the query may be too big - try to increase `memory_limit` php variable in `php.ini`.

Example:

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

Comment: [Read this comment please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27062206/mysql-doesnt-work-properly-when-query-is-very-big#comment42638598_27062206)

Comment: Your query might exceed timeout settings.

Comment: It is slow - (10 - 15s), if so then how can be solved problem?

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on queried columns. Split the query - subqueries tend to be slow.